# ReplicaSet throwing error "selector does not match template labels"

Tags: kubernetes

While creating `ReplicaSet`, I am getting following error:

> The ReplicaSet "julrs" is invalid: spec.template.metadata.labels:
> Invalid value: map[string]string{"type":"july-26"}: `selector` does
> not match template `labels`

Below is my yaml file replicaset.yml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
    name: julrs
    labels:
        type: jul-26
spec:
    template:
       metadata:
           labels:
               type: july-26
       spec:
           containers:
               - name: jul-c1
                 image: nginx
    replicas: 2
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            type: jul-26
```

What am I missing? I have tried `ReplicationController` with the same yaml (without selector and using v1 version) and it was working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the yaml file should be like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: julrs
  labels:
    type: july-26
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: july-26 <-----This 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: july-26 <-------this should be same as above
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jul-c1
        image: nginx
```